# Handlebars doesn't render boolean variables when false

Tags: handlebars.js

Handlebars.js has some weird behavior. It renders a boolean with a value of true as the string "true", but a value of false as "".

```
var booleanTestTrue = true;
var booleanTestFalse = false;
```

Template:

```
True: {{booleanTestTrue}}
False: {{booleanTestFalse}}
```

Renders to:

```
True: true
False: (empty string)
```

Is there any way to fix this problem? Or do I have to write a helper?

Comment: repo issue here: https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/827

Answer (score 23):

You can use a simple block helper and implement #if like the following:

```
{{#if isTrue}}
       true
{{else}}
       false
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to print a string, you should pass a string.

```
false.toString();
```

Otherwise, yeah you would need a helper (unless you use the `#if`|`#unless` helpers to output a string).

On a side note, if you wanted to print these values for debugging purpose, use the `{{log booleanTestFalse}}`.

Answer (score 3):

I was surprised by this, and ended up writing a simple helper for it:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper( 'toString', function returnToString( x ){
    return ( x === void 0 ) ? 'undefined' : x.toString();
} );
```

You would then invoke it as follows:

```
True:  {{toString booleanTestTrue}}
False: {{toString booleanTestFalse}}
```

In most scenarios you could get away with simply `return x.toString()`. The extra checking avoids attempting to call `toString` on undefined values.

Answer (score 1):

I used this, similar to Barney's answer but supports null too.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('toString', function (v) { 
    return '' + v; 
});
```

You would then invoke it as follows:

```
True:  {{toString booleanTestTrue}}
False: {{toString booleanTestFalse}}
```

However if `v` is an object with a pretty `toString` method you need to do more coding.