# Meteor checkbox - Display Value of expression as String, not interpreted as Boolean

Tags: javascript, checkbox, meteor

I have a checkbox implemented and it's working just fine.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <ul>
        {{#each checkbox}}
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="{{checked}}" class="toggle-checked"> {{name}}: {{checked}}
        </li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</form>
```

JS:

```
Cbtest = new Mongo.Collection('cbtest');

Template.checkbox.helpers({
    checkbox: function () {
        return Cbtest.find();
    }
});

Template.checkbox.events({
    "click .toggle-checked": function () {
       var self = this;
        Meteor.call("setChecked", self._id, !self.checked);
    }
});

Meteor.methods({
    setChecked: function (checkboxId, setChecked) {
        Cbtest.update(checkboxId, {
            $set: {
                checked: setChecked
            }
        });
    }
});
```

[image]

I want to display the Value ("true" or "false") depending on the checkbox's state.
As now it seems that the Expression "{{ checked }}" is evaluatiated to true or false, and if its true then it returns the value of the corresponding document entry.
How can i just display the content as String ("true" / "false")?

Thanks in advance!
Vin

Comment: In your meteor method there is a typo in `CbTest`. Should be `Cbtest` I guess ;)

Comment: Thanks - corrected :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add another helper that transforms the `checked` Bool into a String using the `toString()` function:

```
checkedString: function () {
  return this.checked.toString();
}
```

And then use this helper in the template:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="{{checked}}" class="toggle-checked"> {{name}}: {{checkedString}}
```

See this meteor [pad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/AnT6NoqXf4KNFztnP/display-false-in-template) for a demo.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Two questions left:
1.) Why is it that for the expression {{name}} the corresponding String "one" is displayed but if you use {{checked}} its evaluated like an if-Statement (so the toString-Conversion is neccessary)?

2.) A structural question: Why did you put the Meteor.methods into the server folder?

-- Thanks :)

Comment: 1) Apparently this is how handlebars works by design. Here is a handlebars specific [questing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664323/handlebars-doesnt-render-boolean-variables-when-false)

Comment: 2) "When you call any of these (method) functions on the client, you're invoking their stub version that update the local cache, and sending the same write request to the server" (Meteor [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_methods)). Since there is no counterpart for the method on the server there is no endpoint for the request that the client side method sends. Hence you will get the error "Error invoking Method 'setChecked': Method not found [404]" in your browser console. Also: "Calling methods on the client defines stub functions associated with server methods of the same name"

Comment: Thanks! I'm a little confused about when there is server-interaction and when there is none since this "optimistic ui" always seems to sync.
I'm asking because i have a huge array of objects/ data and depending on the client-side input this data is represented differently. But i want to keep the calculations purely client-side to relieve the server. ---
So where do i put the methods for client-side calculations that don't need any server-interaction?

Comment: I don't know a "official" recommended way to do this that is meteor related. Personally I do client(-only) related stuff in helpers or in other functions. In your example the Meteor method was used for updating the database, which does not seem like something that you only want to do on the client ;)